# How to use retire.js for react apps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security

Retire.js is a library which is used for getting security vulnerabilities of JavaScript libraries. I want to use retire.js for react apps. As mentioned in the documentation of [retire.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/retire), I used `retire -p` command where the package.json is placed, but it gives a message like:

> "Missing version for log. Need to run npm install ?"

What does this message mean? How can I use this for react apps?

Answer (score 1):

retire.js needs you to run "npm install" before you run retire (as mentioned in the error message) because retire reads the files in the node_modules folder and reports on anythings it finds there. If npm install has no been run, it doesn't see the installed modules' versions.

The error message above means "retire could not find an installed version of the package log. Please run npm install to ensure all dependencies are installed and then run retire again"